# How to Properly Setup Silvertripe Routes and Controllers and Templates

Tags: php, yaml, silverstripe

How to Properly Setup Silvertripe Routes and Controllers and Pages? I followed the developers documentation as shown below,

TestController.php

```
    class TestController extends Controller {

        private static $allowed_actions = array(
            'test'
        );

        public function test(SS_HTTPRequest $request) {
            print_r('Executing Test Controller inside TestController');
        }

    }
```

routes.yml

```
---
Name: mysiteroutes
After: framework/routes#coreroutes
---
Director:
  rules:
    'test/': 'TestController'
```

My url when entered is http://127.0.0.1/silverstripe/test/.

but the print_r from the test conroller did not appear also return $this->renderWith("Test") did not work. There is an actual Test.ss.

This is what the output was instead

Getting Started

To get started with the SilverStripe framework:

```
Create a Controller subclass (doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/controller)
Setup the routes.yml to your Controller (doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/director#routing).
Create a template for your Controller (doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/templates)
```

Community resources

```
silverstripe.org/forum Discussion forums for the development community.

silverstripe.org/irc IRC channel for realtime support and discussions.

doc.silverstripe.org Searchable developer documentation, how-tos, tutorials, and reference.

api.silverstripe.org API documentation for PHP classes, methods and properties.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Director.rules configuration `test: TestController` binds any URL of the '/test/$Action' pattern to the TestController. Default action is called `index`.

So, if you want to handle just one action, then you don't need $allowed_actions, and rename `test` method to `index`.

Your current controller `test` method handles `/test/test` request.

Default template name is determined from the controller name with pattern TemplateName_Controller. The underscore character splits the name and is equivalent to calling `$this->renderWith(['TemplateName','Controller'])`.

In your case default controller template is "TestController.ss" and custom action template may be "TestController_Test.ss" (as pattern `{$DefaultTemplate}_{$Action}.ss`)

You can debug your request with `?debug=1` and `?debug_request=1` query parameters.

Comment: Did you mean TestController instead of TextController?

Comment: Yes. Edited the answer

Comment: test method handles /test/ not /test/test?

Comment: No, test method handles action 'test' and corresponds to /test/test request. For example you have a controller `Library_Controller` that handles `/library` url segment, then `Library_Controller::books()` method handles `/library/books` url.

Comment: $this->renderWith(['TemplateName','Controller']) works but {$DefaultTemplate}_{$Action}.ss) does not?